# Does 周末那两天 means both Sunday and Saturday?

Tags: simplified-characters

The original sentence is：

> 周末那两天他看电视。

周末那两天 means both Sunday and Saturday?

Comment: ✓ :"on the (those) 2 days of the weekend"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`周末那两天` literally means `Those two days of the weekend`, hence, Saturday and Sunday.

However, numbers in Chinese is not always real numbers.

I think `周末那两天` could mean not only  **exactly** those two days of the weekend， but also **any** day of those two days, **maybe** both of them.

Therefore, `周末那两天他看电视` could mean

`He watches TV on Saturday and Sunday`

`He watched TV on those two days of the weekend`

`He (often) watches TV on weekends`

More contexts are essential to understand a sentence precisely.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like this:

周末 Weekend
那 that/those
两天 2 days
他看电视 he watches telly.

Answer (score 0):

I would say yes to your question, if you think the whole weekend is made up of two days Sat and Sun.

Answer (score 0):

yes, both Sunday and Saturday.